# What is a "side hustle"?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

I can't understand properly from the context is being used in this tweet:

> @Forbes
>   Looking for a team member who takes initiative? Hire someone with a side hustle

And it does not fit in any of the [definitions](http://www.bing.com/search?q=hustle+define):

> VERB
>
> - force (someone) to move hurriedly or unceremoniously in a specified direction:
>     they hustled him into the back of a horse-drawn wagon
> - informal, NORTH AMERICAN: obtain by forceful action or persuasion:
>     the brothers headed to New York to try and hustle a record deal
> - informal, NORTH AMERICAN: engage in prostitution.
>
> NOUN
>
> - busy movement and activity:
>     the hustle and bustle of the big cities
> - informal, NORTH AMERICAN: a fraud or swindle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=side%20hustle):

> **Side hustle** - Sideline that brings in cash; something other than your main job. Maybe playing weekend gigs or life coaching.

**Example:**

*When start up your own business you probably want to get some side hustle going. Maybe a small low stress consulting job on how to get a side hustle going.*

Answer (score 1):

A side hustle is an extra way to make money. Usually this is apart from your day job. "On the side"...

My favorite side hustle? I do dog-walking and pet-sitting on the side, part time. It is a very fun way to make travel money and slow months will earn me 150-200 bucks and my busiest months get me up to $1200.

Answer (score -1):

A side hustle is work you do on the side of your full time job or on the side of your other part time jobs. It can either be work for another employer or a side business you start yourself. It could also be side gigs with apps like uber, airbnb, and task rabbit.